# sub list of linked list in c?

Tags: c, linked-list

I want to make a sub list in a single list using c.  I have a list with name, surname, phone, e-mail….
I want to make a sub list under phone to keep more phones.
This is my struct:

```
typedef struct ph{
    char * phone;
    ph *next;
}listofphones;

typedef struct client{
    char* name;
    char* surname;
    date birthday;
    char bankaccount[16];
    listofphone phone;
    char* mail;
    struct client *next;
} clientData;
```

I want an extra sub-list for any client. The problem is that the phones are all in the same list. So how can I create a different list?

Example:

```
name1->surname1->birthday1->bankaccount1->phone1->mail1.......
                                            |
                                          phone2
                                            |
                                          phone3 
                                            .
                                            .                                                     
                                            .
```

(Sorry for bad drawing I hope it’s clear enough.)

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. Can you draw a picture of how you want clients, phone, and the list of phones to be organized?

Comment: The current code already has a list per client.  I still don't understand the issue?

Comment: It should be fairly easy - your `listofphones` (bad name, btw... perhaps `clientPhone` is better?) already has a `next` pointer. So the first phone number will be added into `clientData->phone`, and you will chain additional phone numbers will be chained through `listofphones.next` (and their `next` pointers).

Comment: Perhaps you have some good reason for using a linked list, but you could just as easily use a dynamically allocated array of phone numbers and a member to indicate the number of elements. Might be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep only the head of the other list in every node of this list. Your structure definition will be something like:

```
typedef struct ph{
    char * phone;
    ph *next;
}listofphones;

typedef struct client{
    char* name;
    char* surname;
    date birthday;
    char bankaccount[16];
    ph* phHead;
    char* mail;
    struct client *next;
} clientData;
```

And now, you have a list inside a list. However, writing code to traverse, find, enumerate the phone numbers for a client will require double pointer indirections which should better be avoided. If you have a finite number of phone numbers for a client, you can change it to something like:

```
typedef struct client{
    char* name;
    char* surname;
    date birthday;
    char bankaccount[16];
    char phNumbers[5][10];
    char* mail;
    struct client *next;
} clientData;
```

The above definition of struct assumes that there will be a maximum of 5 phone numbers per client and every phone number will have at most 10 characters. You can change this to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to make another list? Managing pointers will become a headache. Can't you simply do

```
typedef struct client{
char* name;
char* surname;
date birthday;
char bankaccount[16];
int **phone;
char* mail;
struct client *next;
} clientData;
```

Comment: Uhm, why do you need an 10 arrays of 10 integers each?

Comment: umm.. To store ten numbers and generally a phone number has 10 digits in it. I guess I don't understand your question.

Comment: Okay, the OP changed the question so my answer is stale now

Comment: that's a bad assumption (the length of a phone number) but you're allocating way more space than you need anyways, even if you want to store 10 digit numbers. You're allocating enough space for *10* different 10-digit numbers.

Comment: 10 digits ? to witch country does this apply ? with area code or without ? with country code or without ? with `+` or `00` before country code ?? and why only ten phone numbers ??

Comment: Alright, not allocating the memory. Thanks for pointing those out :)

Comment: int **phone; I don’t think so.  Ok maybe this it’s a bad assumption but the question says to make a sub list; (I don’t want something static), is not up to me.